# How to update variable values on resize inside click event jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a click event for my hamburger menu. To position this menu correctly I have used a couple variables. My only problem is when the screen size changes I need to update the values of these variables so that the menu always stays in the correct position. I have tried using a jQuery(window).resize function to reset the values but its not working and I don't get why.

```
jQuery("#button").click(function(){
    var nav = jQuery("#nav_container");
    var head_h = jQuery('#fullhead_wrap').height();
    var nav_height = jQuery(window).height() - head_h;

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        var new_head_h = jQuery('#fullhead_wrap').height();
        head_h = new_head_h;

        var new_nav_height = jQuery(window).height() - new_head_h;
        nav_height = new_nav_height;
    });

    jQuery("#button span").toggleClass("open");
    jQuery("body").toggleClass("overflow");
    jQuery('.header_nav li').toggleClass('link_fall');
    nav.toggleClass('menu_open');

    nav.height(nav_height);

    if(nav.hasClass('menu_open')){
        nav.css('top', head_h);
    }else{
        nav.css('top', '0');
    }
});
```

Comment: Make a fiddle or something for people to take a look.

Comment: Every time you click on `#button` you install a new `resize` event listener. That crashes. Also try with `html,body` instead of `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, you have nested `resize event` in `click event`. You should separate it to get it work.

```
var variables_which_are_used_by_both_events; //...
// put this variables here such as nav_height and head_h
// In some cases it's better to update their value in each event 

jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    var nav = jQuery("#nav_container");
    var head_h = jQuery('#fullhead_wrap').height();
    var nav_height = jQuery(window).height() - head_h;
});

jQuery("#button").click(function(){
    var nav = jQuery("#nav_container");
    var head_h = jQuery('#fullhead_wrap').height();
    var nav_height = jQuery(window).height() - head_h;
   // your code...
});
```